# How to position text and images in a responsive way, with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

Im trying to position this image and tittle with text on my website.
How can I make it responsive so that the scale doesnt change on different devices and everything stays at the same position.
Im new at this, so im probably making a lot of mistakes.

```css
div.content {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

div.column1 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.column2 {
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lobby {
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  padding-top: 5.6rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.title {
  padding-top: 4.7rem;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.descr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="column1">

  </div>

  <div class="column2">


    <div class="title">Installations
      <p class="descr"> We are a gym based in Carballo, A Coruña, counting with an installation </p>
    </div>
    <img class="lobby" src="img/lobby.jpg" alt="photo of the lobby of the gym" />
  </div>

</div>


<div class="column1">

</div>
```

As you can see im trying to position the image and the text on the middle row of my website, since it is divided into 3 columns.

Anything I can do to improve the code and to make it more responsive.
Thanks!

Comment: I'll suggest to read about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). P.s don't use `float` to position text to the right side use `text-align:right` instead

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3 columns. My approach starts defining the wrapper layout (the container), then working on the content layout (2 columns nested on the wrapper).

Here is my way of doing it:

HTML

```
<div class="main-container container">
    <div class="inner-container content">
        <div class="column-left column column-1">
            <img class="lobby" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cb/Placeholder_logo.png" alt="photo of the lobby of the gym">
        </div>
        <div class="column-right column column-2">
            <h1 class="title">Installations</h1>
            <p class="descr">We are a gym based in Carballo, A Coruña, counting with an installation </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
html,
    body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    /* set the layout */
    .main-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 15%;
        padding-right: 15%;
        position: relative;
    }

    /* this is a pseudo element, it renders the grey background on the left */
    .main-container:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #F7F7F7;
        /* same width of padding-left as it covers only the left side */
        width: 15%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .inner-container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 2rem 1rem 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .column {
        padding: 3.6rem 0 1rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* Column width - Change this with media Queryes */
        width: 50%;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }

    /* page elements*/
    .title {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .descr {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding-left: 3rem;
    }

    .lobby {
        width: 45%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /* responsive media query */
    /* decide the breakpoint to start having 1 column */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .column {
            width: 100% !important;
            flex-basis: 100%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Here is a working Codepen: https://codepen.io/Davevvave/pen/BaPZRbb

Consider the @Sfili_81 advice, first study and learn about @media_queries (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp), avoid float, and
(I suggest) try to understand the natural behavior of HTML rendering flux, the semantic meaning of HTML tags and empower all with CSS.